# How to switch user to subuid running LXC container?

Tags: linux, sudo, su, container, lxc

I'd like to either use `su` or `sudo -u` to switch users to the subuid created by LXC to run a container as unprivileged.

Note:

- There is no username assigned to the UIDs in which containers are run.
- Due to the above, I need to be able to switch purely by UID.

I've tried doing as [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/948025/987302) instructed, but I get the following:

```
[user@laptop user]# sudo -u \#100000 id
sudo: unknown user #100000
```

If It's somehow helpful:

- I'm using Arch Linux
- I'm using LXD to manage to container(s)

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this, even if via another command or method?

Answer (score 0):

### As asked in question's body

> I'd like to either use `su` or `sudo -u` to switch users to the subuid

> even if via another command or method?

The [`setpriv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setpriv.1.html) command, part of `util-linux` is documented as:

> In comparison to `su`(1) and `runuser`(1), **`setpriv` neither uses PAM, nor
> does it prompt for a password**. It is a simple, **non-set-user-ID wrapper**
> around `execve`(2), and can be used to drop privileges in the same way
> as `setuidgid`(8) from `daemontools`, `chpst`(8) from `runit`, or similar
> tools shipped by other service managers.

So it must be run as root (prepend `sudo`  if needed):

```shell
root# setpriv --reuid 100000 id
uid=100000 gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

```shell
user$ sudo setpriv --reuid 100000 id
uid=100000 gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

This command has other complementary uses. For example it can also change the capabilities sets of the process.

---

### As asked in question's title

> Switch user to subuid running LXC container

Can be done as it's done for a running container: with an [user namespace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/user_namespaces.7.html) and some help.

One can use the actual underlying setuid-root helper allowing a normal user to run containers: [`newuidmap`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/newuidmap.1.html) (and [`newgidmap`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/newgidmap.1.html)), part of package `uidmap` which is recommended by packages `lxc`, `lxd` or any container technology for non-root users.

```shell
$ newuidmap -h 
usage: newuidmap <pid> <uid> <loweruid> <count> [ <uid> <loweruid> <count> ] ...
```

The value 100000 **must** be part of a range defined in `/etc/subuid` for the invoking user, even if the user is `root`: don't use `sudo`. This part is all done without `root` privilege (thanks to `newuidmap` being setuid-root).

So assuming the value 100000 is part of a range defined for the user `user` in `/etc/subuidmap` (resp. `/etc/subgidmap`) one can the run these two parts (using for example two terminals), one can map the user as root and also map 100000 as the current user: user will become root and will be able to affect UID 100000 (and nothing else).

term1:

```shell
user$ unshare -U
nobody$ echo $$
42151
```

term2:

- use the PID result above
- replace `$(ud -u user)` by the actual user's UID like 1000 if needed
- while at it also map the GID

```shell
newuidmap 42151 0 $(id -u user) 1 $(id -u user) 100000 1
newgidmap 42151 0 $(id -g user) 1 $(id -g user) 100000 1
```

term1 again. Re-exec `bash` so it updates its knowledge of its own user (just cosmetic): `root` (within the user namespace). `root` can now use `setpriv` to become user 1000 in the namespace seen as user 100000 on the host.

```shell
nobody$ exec bash
root# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),65534(nogroup)
root# touch /tmp/mytest
root# setpriv --reuid user --regid user --keep-groups bash
user$ touch /tmp/mytest2
user$
```

With some additional care (as well as additional mappings rather than just 100000), one could even have *chroot*-ed to the actual container storage to directly affect it, e.g. when the container is not started, if it itself includes the tools required after the `chroot` (such as `mount` (but then an additional `unshare -m` is probably also needed before `chroot`), `setpriv` ...). Note: the user 1000 in a typical container might actually map to something else such as 101000 (or 100999 or 101001 ...) if the allowed range starts at 100000.

On term2 (the real host) check the results:

```shell
$ ls -ln /tmp/mytest*
-rw-r--r-- 1   1000   1000 0 Sep 22 11:45 /tmp/mytest
-rw-r--r-- 1 100000 100000 0 Sep 22 11:46 /tmp/mytest2
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here with a similar problem, trying to access files created by a mapped user in a container.

This is the file I am trying to read:

```
$ stat -c uid=%u:%U,gid=%g:%G var/log
uid=207347:UNKNOWN,gid=207347:UNKNOWN
```

If we assume inside the container, the user has $uid and $gid, based on @a-b answer I managed to do it like this:

```
$ unshare --map-users=auto --map-groups=auto --map-user 0 --map-group 0 setpriv --reuid $uid --regid $gid --clear-groups stat -c uid=%u:%U,gid=%g:%G var/log
uid=41812:UNKNOWN,gid=41812:UNKNOWN
```

And 41812 is the uid and gid of the file as seen from inside the container.